# How to easily copy CDN links to multiple html pages

Tags: html, cdn

Is there a way to easily copy CDN links to different html pages?

For example, I have these CDNs:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Now, I need to also include them in other pages as well, but it would be impractical to copy-paste this in multiple other pages. Is there a way to include these CDNs in one page and just call that page?

Comment: Are you using only HTML? If you are using PHP you can create a Page where you can put all link in this Page and call It in the other Pages...

Comment: Do you use any pre-processor for HTML?

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/shtml.htm

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer: Yes!

Long answer: It depends on the setup you have.

If you are using a server-side templating system or a preprocessor, you can do this.
You can also do this if you have a node server. Or if you are using webpack, you could integrate this into your build process.

But if you are writing pure html css and javascript, and use a static site hosting you can't really do this.